# Maximum in a sliding window

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

i am unable to detect why i am getting wrong answer in the problem subarrays given on spoj .The problem is to determine the maximum element in k sized window .
i have applied sliding window algorithm which uses deque and maintains the index of the maximum element always at the front.

here is my code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<deque>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    cin>>n;

    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
     }
    int k;
    cin>>k;

    deque<int>q;
    int ans[n-k+1];
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        while(!q.empty()&&arr[i]>=arr[q.back()])
            q.pop_back();

        q.push_back(i);
    }

    for(int i=k;i<n;i++)
    {
        ans[i-k]=arr[q.front()];

        while(!q.empty()&&arr[i]>=arr[q.back()])
            q.pop_back();

        while(!q.empty()&&q.front()<=i-k)
            q.pop_front();

        q.push_back(i);
    }
    ans[n-k]=arr[q.front()];

    for(int i=0;i<=n-k;i++)
    {
    cout<<ans[i];
    }
    cout<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code so it's readable.  Have you tried using a debugger to see where it goes wrong?  You didn't say anything about what kind of errors you're getting.

Comment: It is not clear what your code is doing. But I think you can solve this with array which will also be simpler.

Comment: I am getting the right answer with the test case given on the spoj website   but still getting wrong answer when i submit their    i think some test cases are missing  cant find them ?    i am using sliding window algorithm given on leetcode.com ...... i am solving ARRAYSUB problem on spoj

Comment: Put curvy brackets for all your for loops. Not only it tidy the codes but also provides better readability.

Comment: i have edited my code for better readability !

Answer (score 0):

Simple C++ logic would be...

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
int temp;
int A[] = {1,2,-1,7,8,-3,-4};
int max = A[0];
printf("%d\n",max);
int n = 7;
for(int i = 1 ; i <= n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <= n-i ; j++)
    {
        temp = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            temp+=A[j+k];
        }
        if(temp > max)
        max = temp;
        //printf("%d\n",max);
    }
}
printf("%d\n",max);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a simple array. I am writing the Java solution which you can change into your preferred language.

```
public class SlidingWindowMaximum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] arr={1,3,-1,-3,5,3,6, 7};
       int winSize=3;
       int[] arrMax=getMax(arr,winSize);
       display(arrMax);
}
```

// This method gives you the array of the mx value for SlidingWindow problem.

```
private static int[] getMax(int[] A,int B){
List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
int[] tempA=new int[B];

for(int i=0;i<A.length-B+1;i++){
        int tempi=0;
     for(int j=i;j<i+B;j++){
        tempA[tempi]=A[j];
        tempi++;
      }
    int retMax=getMaxValueFromSortedArray(tempA);
    list.add(retMax);
    }
    int[] array = list.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
    return array;
}
```

// This method gives you the maxValue from the window of size required.

```
private static int getMaxValueFromSortedArray(int[] tempA){
       int maxValue=0;
    for(int j=0;j<tempA.length;j++){
        Arrays.sort(tempA);
        maxValue=tempA[tempA.length-1];
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

// Display metod to print array elements.

```
    private static void display(int[] arr){
        for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.print(" "+arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged C++. OP is expecting a solution in C++.